# Could not find support-fragment.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:27.0.2)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I cloned my project and opened with Android studio, but the build fails with the below error and **same project is working fine for others**.

- What went wrong:
  Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:flavorUnsignedReleaseCompileClasspath'.

  > Could not find support-fragment.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:27.0.2).
  >   Searched in the following locations:
  >     https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/support-fragment/27.0.2/support-fragment-27.0.2.jar

Comment: Clean and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just had the issue myself and fixed it by deleting Gradle's cache. On Linux you would find the cache here:

```
~/.gradle/caches
```

Afterwards do a full build and it should be working.

Comment: I didn't want to mess with files manually - because I had some bad experience from deleting the gradle cache by hand -, so I tried project clean/rebuild, clean gradle cache with gradle task and other methods without any success. Finally I gave up on avoding this method and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Run in terminal: on Windows: gradlew cleanBuildCache, on mac/unix: ./gradlew cleanBuildCache