# Could not find fragment.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0)

Tags: android, android-fragments

When I try to compile the project I get this error:

> Could not find fragment.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0).

what is the problem?

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.apps"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

//        externalNativeBuild {
//            cmake {
//                cppFlags ""
//            }
//        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
//    externalNativeBuild {
//        cmake {
//            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
//            version "3.10.2"
//        }
//    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04'

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.17'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.17'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.17'

    /* Dagger2 - default dependency */
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.17'
}
```

**build errors:**

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
    at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:kapt'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultConfiguration.java:1195)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.access$2100(DefaultConfiguration.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$ConfigurationFileCollection.getFiles(DefaultConfiguration.java:1170)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileCollection.iterator(AbstractFileCollection.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.iterator(DefaultConfiguration.java:467)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileCollection.iterator(CompositeFileCollection.java:64)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.SubpluginUtilsKt$withWrappedKaptOptions$1.apply(subpluginUtils.kt:100)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.SubpluginUtilsKt$withWrappedKaptOptions$1.apply(subpluginUtils.kt)
    at java.util.HashMap.compute(HashMap.java:1197)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.SubpluginUtilsKt.withWrappedKaptOptions(subpluginUtils.kt:56)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.SubpluginUtilsKt.withWrappedKaptOptions$default(subpluginUtils.kt:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptGenerateStubsTask.setupCompilerArgs(KaptGenerateStubsTask.kt:85)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptGenerateStubsTask.setupCompilerArgs(KaptGenerateStubsTask.kt:36)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAware$DefaultImpls.setupCompilerArgs$default(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAwareKt.prepareCompilerArguments(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:44)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAwareKt.prepareCompilerArguments$default(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:43)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAware$DefaultImpls.getFilteredArgumentsMap(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:37)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.CompilerArgumentAwareWithInput$DefaultImpls.getFilteredArgumentsMap(CompilerArgumentAware.kt:61)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompileTool.getFilteredArgumentsMap(Tasks.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptGenerateStubsTask_Decorated.getFilteredArgumentsMap(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.bean.AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode$BeanPropertyValue$1$1.create(AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.SingleMessageLogger.whileDisabled(SingleMessageLogger.java:341)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.bean.AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode$BeanPropertyValue$1.get(AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode.java:72)
    at com.google.common.base.Suppliers$NonSerializableMemoizingSupplier.get(Suppliers.java:167)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.bean.AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode$BeanPropertyValue.call(AbstractNestedRuntimeBeanNode.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.AbstractValidatingProperty.validate(AbstractValidatingProperty.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.properties.DefaultTaskProperties.validate(DefaultTaskProperties.java:184)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find fragment.jar (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.0.0).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/fragment/fragment/1.0.0/fragment-1.0.0.jar
    at org.gradle.internal.resolve.result.DefaultBuildableArtifactResolveResult.notFound(DefaultBuildableArtifactResolveResult.java:27)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$LocateInCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifactFromCache(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:335)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$LocateInCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:290)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.lambda$resolveArtifact$15(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:185)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.tryResolveAndMaybeBlacklist(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:241)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.performOperationWithRetries(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:207)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:183)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(RepositoryChainArtifactResolver.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.DefaultArtifactSet$LazyArtifactSource.create(DefaultArtifactSet.java:183)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.DefaultArtifactSet$LazyArtifactSource.create(DefaultArtifactSet.java:170)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.DefaultResolvedArtifact.getFile(DefaultResolvedArtifact.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNode$InitialTransformationNode$1.transform(TransformationNode.java:150)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNode$ArtifactTransformationStepBuildOperation.call(TransformationNode.java:229)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNode$ArtifactTransformationStepBuildOperation.call(TransformationNode.java:212)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNode$InitialTransformationNode.execute(TransformationNode.java:145)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.transform.TransformationNodeExecutor.execute(TransformationNodeExecutor.java:37)
    ... 15 more
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Could not find support-fragment.jar (com.android.support:support-fragment:27.0.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50922529/could-not-find-support-fragment-jar-com-android-supportsupport-fragment27-0-2)

Comment: @Behzad, I have updated my answer please check.

Answer (score 12):

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: You must enter this code in "allprojects"  and delete google(). and insert this code>> 

maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }

Comment: Thanks. I replaced google() with  maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'} and problem solved.

Comment: do you have any idea why we must use this way ?

Answer (score 8):

its probably too late but just replace google() with

```
maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        name 'Google'
}
```

in your project level gradle file

Answer (score 0):

I have copied your Gradle update the **buildToolsVersion** to **"29.0.3"** and check with my environment. It is working fine and build successfully.

**your Gradle file should look like**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.daggerdemo"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

//        externalNativeBuild {
//            cmake {
//                cppFlags ""
//            }
//        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
//    externalNativeBuild {
//        cmake {
//            path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
//            version "3.10.2"
//        }
//    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

    implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.1.1'
    annotationProcessor 'android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1'
    kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.1.1"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha04'

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.17'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.17'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.17'

    /* Dagger2 - default dependency */
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.17'
}
```

and make sure your project-level Gradle works file and SDK components are updated.

**here is my project level Gradle file:**

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.61'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: not work for me. I use `maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }` too

Comment: did you check the build log? I will tell you the reason for the error

Comment: @Behzad, Can you please upload your project level Gradle file?